# Loading a csv file to an sql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I need to load a csv file of students into a table in my database called student.
When I run this code:

```
<?php require ('../connect_db.php');?>
<?php
$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:\xampp\htdocs\student.csv'
    INTO TABLE student
    [FIELDS 
        [TERMINATED BY ',']
        [ENCLOSED BY '""']
    ]
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (Student_ID,Forename,Surname,@Date_Of_Birth,Year_Group)
    SET Date_Of_Birth = STR_TO_DATE(@Date_Of_Birth, '%d/%m/%Y');
eof;

if (mysqli_query($dbc, $query)) {
        #If the query is successfully completed the following will be displayed
        echo "New students created successfully";
    } else {
        #This outputs any error that may occur to do with the query
        echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($dbc);
    }#This c
?>
```

I get this error:

> Error: LOAD DATA INFILE 'E: mpp\htdocs\student.csv' INTO TABLE student [FIELDS [TERMINATED BY ','] [ENCLOSED BY '""'] ] LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 ROWS (Student_ID,Forename,Surname,@Date_Of_Birth,Year_Group) SET Date_Of_Birth = STR_TO_DATE(@Date_Of_Birth, '%d/%m/%Y');
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[FIELDS [TERMINATED BY ','] [ENCLOSED BY '""'] ] LINES TERMINATED BY ' at line 3

What should I do?

Comment: The brackets in the documentation are signifying options, you don't actually put the options in brackets.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the [] brackets from the code but am now left with this error:                                                                                                          Error: LOAD DATA INFILE 'E: mpp\htdocs\student.csv' INTO TABLE student FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '""' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 ROWS (Student_ID,Forename,Surname,@Date_Of_Birth,Year_Group) SET Date_Of_Birth = STR_TO_DATE(@Date_Of_Birth, '%d/%m/%Y');
Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual

Comment: Yes... and did you read the error?  It states the issue right there.